# How to insert value in a column of a table based on a selection of another table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need help to correct the following code:

```
UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.col_2 = '1'
FROM table_2 
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_2.col_1 = table_1.col_1 
AND table_1.col_2 IN (2,6,11,16,19,22);
```

There are 2 tables that have the same first column (that is, `col_1` is the same for `table_1` and `table_2`).

The second column of `table_1` is filled with numbers, while the second column of `table_2` is empty.

I need to check the rows of `col_2` of `table_1` that have the same values as 2, 6, 11, 16, 19 or 22. Then, I need to insert the value `"1"` in the respective cell of `col_2` of `table_2` that shares the same value for `col_1`.

The below picture makes it easier to understand:

[image: The picture bellow makes it easier to understand.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the MySQL `UPDATE .. JOIN ... SET` syntax:

```
UPDATE table_2 t2
INNER JOIN table_1 t1 
    ON t2.col_1 = t1.col_1 
    AND t1.col_2 IN (2, 6, 11, 16, 19, 22)
SET t2.col_2 = 1
```

NB: I assume that `table_2.col_2` is of numeric datatype, so I removed the single quotes around `'1'`.